# How to display images from an array in Flex?

Tags: arrays, apache-flex, image, mxml

I'm making a Matching Game in Flex. I want to have images from one array on my left and images from the second array on my right, so that user can drag&drop images from the left onto matching images on the right.

I have mx:HBox and two mx:VBox inside. Now, how can I display images in VBox that I have in my gameArray, if the length of my array (amount of images) may differ? I would have to create as many mx:Image as the length of my gameArray, but how do I do it in MXML?

Answer (score 4):

Why not use a [List](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html) with an [itemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html) to display the image?

Answer (score -1):

I have all my data in an array and prefer to keep it like this. I just dont understand why my code doesn't work...

```
<mx:ArrayCollection id="myAC" source="{gameArray}"/>
<mx:VBox width="50%" height="100%">
<mx:Repeater id="rp" dataProvider="{myAC}">
<mx:Image source="{rp.currentItem}"/>
</mx:Repeater>
</mx:VBox>
```

The code is taken straight from http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=repeater_3.html

Why doesn't it display the images? I debugged my code to make sure that the array has correct data. The string in, e.g. gameArray[1] will be "assets/image.jpg" and if I just write it as a source, it works. With dynamic, it does not. Maybe rp.currentItem is not exactly what I should use in this case??

Comment: It is considered proper etiquette to add these sort of details by editing your question; not as an answer.  Unless your myAC is an array of Strings the source 'rp.currentItem' will probably not be a valid source.

Comment: ok, sorry, i didn't know that. well, the thing is that gameArray is definitely an array of strings (paths to the files). i don't know if something is changing once i convert it into an arraycollection? but when I add a txt area to check in every loop the value of rp.currentItem, it's always null. so i'm not surprised it doesn't display the files, the question is only what happened to my strings from gameArray??

Comment: show us the code that creates your dataProvider.  Really, I believe you'll solve a lot of issues if you stop trying to use a repeater and use a list again.  I think repeaters execute early on in the component lifecycle; most likely before you populate myAC w/ data.

Comment: the reason why i didnt want to use lists etc is that i'm new to flex/as and have never used an itemrenderer, so wouldnt even know how to start... anyway, i finally realized that this statement: "myAC= new ArrayCollection(gameArray)" was in a wrong place in my code... so that my gameArray was fine, just myAC wasnt populated. now it works just fine! :D